# how can i return the nodes in pre-order from encoded tuple

Tags: python, tuples, decode

It's my first question here so please forgive me if smth's wrong with it.

Got a binary tree encoded as a `tuple(node_label, left_node_tuple, right_node_tuple)`, I have to write an iterator / generator that returns the nodes of the tree in pre-order.

ex:

Input: `('b', ('a', None, None), ('z', ('c', None, None), ('zz', None, None)))`

Output: `b, a, z, c, zz`

How can i solve that?

Thanx

Comment: The next time incorporate what you have done yourself in the question. Without that questions are usually candidates for downvoting and closing.

Comment: what all you have tried ?

Comment: Thank you for you advice and accorded help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tree = ('b', ('a', None, None), ('z', ('c', None, None), ('zz', None, None)))

def breadth_first(tree):
    root, left_sub_tree, right_sub_tree = tree
    yield root
    for subtree in (left_sub_tree, right_sub_tree):
        if subtree is not None:
            for element in breadth_first(subtree):
                yield element


    print list(breadth_first(tree))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'z', 'c', 'zz']
```